# (Human) Language proficiency in Developer Story

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, developer-story, languages

Even though this is an English-speaking community, there are many non-English-speaking companies recruiting through the users' *Developer Story* tab. For example, in the *Developer Jobs* tab, job offers that are written in German or French can be found.

A *milestone* will do for specifying a language proficiency certificate in the Developer Story tab, but how would be the proper way to specify a user's estimated language proficiency in the *Developer Story* tab? It seems that there is no specific field for that.

Comment: You could just put "fluent in French and German" (or similar) in your intro.?

Comment: are there any news on this ?

Comment: @Gonzalo.- I haven't seen any change so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this time, there is no dedicated field on developer story for natural language proficiency.

We've gotten similar feedback from both sides (employers and candidates), and
it is something we're actively working on and hope to have an update in the near future.

Really, I'm not making this up! We already have a Trello card for it! :-)

[image]

Comment: Oh, great! Thanks for the info, I'm glad to hear that. I think that being able to classify the language proficiency as beginner, intermediate or advance (or [a similar scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages)) would be a great improvement for the Developer Story tab.

Comment: Looking at the card, I'm sure there will also be employers *in* North America who need this; French will be essential for some types of jobs in Canada, apart of course from companies who develop for an international audience or local minorities.